# Dynamics 2011 QueryString Wrong

Tags: javascript, .net, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I have some JavaScript registered to the OnLoad event of the Appointment edit page in Dynamics 2011.

I have another page that launches a popup with the following url:

```
http://dynamicsserver/main.aspx?etn=appointment&extraqs=etc%3d4201& 
pagetype=entityrecord#myextraparameter=1
```

Note the myextraparameter=1 at the end. I need to get that parameter value in my OnLoad JavaScript....but the window.location in my JavaScript returns the following:

```
http://dynamicsserver/OrgName/userdefined/edit.aspx?etc=4201&pagemode=iframe&sitemappath=Workplace%7cMyWork%7ccnav_dashboards#
```

instead of the actual URL I need. What's more interesting is that at the top of the popup window, in the address bar, the URL is reflected correctly as

```
http://dynamicsserver/main.aspx?etn=appointment&extraqs=etc%3d4201& 
pagetype=entityrecord#myextraparameter=1
```

`Xrm.Page.context.getQueryStringParameters()` returns the same useless URL's parameters, not the one I need.

How can I get my parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CRM restricts arbitrary query string parameters from forms.

You can customize a form to accept query string parameters that you can then grab with the Xrm.Page.context.getQueryStringParameters() method you've already referenced, the SDK has the details: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334436.aspx